# python unicode #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- not doing the job...where to encode?I think I need to remove str and encode

Tags: python, ajax, django, unicode, utf-8

Hello this is what I want to do; I simply want to switch a word,"with" here with non-english, translation of the word "with".

```
return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s</a>" %context
```

I'm unable to use other non-english in the return. I don't know why...I have python file, I'm using django, and have put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
at the top of my python file

This is my full code

```
def __unicode__(self):

        target_url = self.target_object.get_absolute_url()

        context = {
            "sender":self.sender_object,
            "verb":self.verb,
            "action":self.action_object,
            "target":self.target_object,
            "verify_read": reverse("notifications_read", kwargs={"id": self.id}),
            "target_url":target_url,
        }
        if self.target_object:
            if self.action_object and target_url:
                return "%(sender)s %(verb)s <a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(target)s</a> with %(action)s" %context
            if self.action_object and not target_url:
                return "%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s" %context
            return "%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s" %context
        return "%(sender)s %(verb)s" %context

    @property   
    def get_link(self):
        try:
            target_url = self.target_object.get_absolute_url()
        except:
            target_url = reverse("notifications_all")

        context = {
            "sender": self.sender_object,
            "verb": self.verb,
            "action": self.action_object,
            "target": self.target_object,
            "verify_read": reverse("notifications_read", kwargs={"id": self.id}),
            "target_url": target_url,
        }
        if self.target_object:
            return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s</a>" %context
        else:
            return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s</a>" %context
```

Edit:I had similar problem, and I solved it by removing string and encode

```
@login_required
def get_notifications_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        notifications = Notification.objects.all_for_user(MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)).recent()
        count = notifications.count()
        notes = []
        for note in notifications:
            notes.append(note.get_link.encode('utf-8'))
        data = {
            "notifications": notes,
            "count": count,
        }
        print data
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        print json_data
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

I encoded this line;

```
notes.append(note.get_link.encode('utf-8'))
```

I think I need to do similar thing but don't know

Comment: So what's the error you're getting? Do you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of your module, since you're not using explicit unicode literals, but you're apparently still using the ancient Python 2?

Comment: yeah I'm using python2, I get ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb

Comment: @koniiiik with the one I'm using ajax for I get ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb but the one I don't use ajax for, the whole return statement doesn't appear

Comment: I don't understand your second comment, to be honest, but you haven't answered the more interesting question – have you tried using unicode literals instead of bytestrings?

Comment: You already have a similar question: [the moment I put a string that's non-english word, whole thing disappears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643855/the-moment-i-put-a-string-thats-non-english-word-whole-thing-disappears)

Comment: @koniiiik no frankly I don't know what that is, I've just been adding #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the top of my python file and I could've used non-english word anytime....watI's unicode_literals and how do I use it?

Comment: @AKS no sir I didn't put anything clear there because I didn't know the problem now that I know little bit more I have added the question with detailed problems

Comment: @koniiiik what is from __future__ import unicode_literals?

Comment: Have you tried to put that into a search engine? You literally only have to copy-paste the question you asked in your previous comment into a search engine to find out.

Comment: @koniiiik I meant to ask how does from future import unicode_literals help my situation?just putting from future import unicode_literals at the top won't do the job, so I need to use unicode_literals somewhere...but I don't know where....I did something similar for other problem but that time I knew I had to remove str...but this time I don't know...(please see the editted question

Comment: The only way to properly fix this problem is to learn how Python handles Unicode. You might be able to get rid of this error by trial and error, but even if you do, unless you understand how to handle Unicode in Python, your application will almost certainly still be broken wrt. non-ASCII text. You should learn what the difference between bytestrings and Unicode strings in Python is, you can't meaningfully move forward without that.

Comment: @koniiiik so you don't know eh

Answer (score 1):

The `__unicode__()` magic method MUST return a `unicode` string (an instance of the `unicode` type), but you are returning a byte string (instance of the `str` type).

Adding the "# coding" mark on top of you code won't turn byte strings into unicode ones, it will only tells Python that your byte strings litterals are utf-8 encoded - but they are *still* byte strings.

The solution is dead simple: make sure you return a `unicode` string. First make sure each and every string in your `context` is `unicode`, then make all your litteral strings `unicode` too by prefixing them with a `u`, ie:

```
return u"%(sender)s %(verb)s <a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(target)s</a> with %(action)s" % context
# ...
return u"%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s" % context
# ...
return u"%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s" % context
# ...
return u"%(sender)s %(verb)s" %  context
```

If you don't grasp the difference between a unicode string and a utf-8 encoded byte string, you definitly want to read this : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thank you very much while I this works, I just have one more question if you don't mind how is from __future__ import unicode_literals different from # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- I'll read more about these for sure but i would appreciate it if you explain me about unicode_literals

Comment: @mikebraa, `#coding: utf8` only informs Python of the encoding of your source file.  If you have no non-ASCII characters in your *source file*, it has no effect.  Byte strings remain byte strings.  `from __future__ import unicode_literals` makes strings like `"xxxx"` Unicode strings by default instead of byte strings, like Python 3.